# faster way to replacing specific values per column, python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large-ish structure in as a pandas dataframe, shape =  (2000, 200000) I want to replace all of the values of 2 in each column with that particular columns mean (excluding the 2 values). This is how I do it for small structures, but for larger ones it takes a significantly longer time. `Y` is the DataFrame.

```
for i in Y.columns:
    x = Y[i][Y[i] != 2].mean()
    Y[i][Y[i] == 2] = x
```

Is there a faster solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is `df`, Let:

```
a = df.values
```

I'd calculate what the average is across non-twos with

```
avg = (a.sum(0) - (a == 2).sum(0) * 2.) / (a != 2).sum(0)
```

`(a == 2).sum(0)` is the number of `2`s in each column.

Then use `np.where` to select between `a` and `avg`.  Wrap it in a `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(a != 2, a, avg), df.index, df.columns)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are working with arithmetic operations, I would suggest offloading all those computations to NumPy, get the final result and create a dataframe, like so -

```
# Extract into an array
arr = Y.values

# Mask to set or not-set elements in array
mask = arr!=2

# Compute the mean vaalues for masked elements along each column
avg = np.true_divide((arr*mask).sum(0),mask.sum(0))

# Finally choose values based on mask and create output dataframe
Yout = pd.DataFrame(np.where(~mask,avg,arr),columns=Y.columns)
```

For further performance boost, you can probably replace `(arr*mask).sum(0)`
 with `np.einsum('ij,ij->j',arr,mask)` as `np.einsum` is very efficient in most cases.

Verify results with a sample run -

```
In [128]: Y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,(10,5)))

In [129]: arr = Y.values
     ...: mask = arr!=2
     ...: avg = np.true_divide((arr*mask).sum(0),mask.sum(0))
     ...: Yout = pd.DataFrame(np.where(~mask,avg,arr),columns=Y.columns)
     ...: 

In [130]: for i in Y.columns:
     ...:     x = Y[i][Y[i] != 2].mean()
     ...:     Y[i][Y[i] == 2] = x
     ...:     

In [131]: np.allclose(Y,Yout)
Out[131]: True
```

Comment: both great answers, thank you! I'm accepting piRSquared as it does the job quickly (as does yours)and he got to question an hour earlier (so had I been awake I would have accepted it).